Dinner With Jackson Pollock
Here is the riddle I created in 2024 that I'm most satisfied with—it's very much in my personal style (I study fine arts and design). I once posted it on my personal page, but sadly, I don't think many people have seen it. So, I'm sharing it here, hoping you'll like it! It a puzzle hunt style puzzle, so the answer is an English word.
Dinner With Jackson Pollock
Some abstract artists invite you to dinner, and while you're there, you'll also get to see their latest "paintings".

Dinner Recipe (Lexicographical order)

Canned leguminous subfamily herbs and their juice (4/3 5)
Colorless organic adhesive (1/5 5 2 7)
Concentrate of lycopene with decarbonized formaldehyde suspension(1/10)
Cooked and mashed product of the tuberous part of the Devil's
fruit (5/9)
Sponge-like dairy-based pastry with dairy by-products (4/4 4)
Synthetic resin-based coating of organic pigments (15/3 7 6 2 7)
Transparent high-molecular viscous polymer (3/8 2 6)

HINT

 If you have figured out what those "Dinner Recipe" really are, you may google them with the keyword "artworks".


Is the meaning of the numbers in the brackets part of the puzzle or can you explain these?

@quarague: They are part of this enigmatic puzzle. If you can make enough sense of the hint, they explain themselves.

[Partial, but nearly there: I'm missing one item from the recipe.]
The answer is:

 PASTELS.

The Pollockesque smears on the paintings ...

 ... are the result of several attacks on paintings in museums. Around 2022, activist groups glued themselves to paintings or threw substances at these paintings. (The small dark spots you see in paintings #1 and #6 are hands. Some useful articles on the subject are informative, but unfortunately not exhaustive.)

 The recipe describes the used substances and adhesives in a chemical-biological jumbo mumbo. The enumerations after the slash denote how many letters are in each word of the artwork's title.

With that, we get ...

 ... the following list of artworks:

  van Gogh - The Sower, bathed in pea soup, #7
  van Gogh - Peach Trees in Blossom, glued to activists, #1
  van Gogh - Sunflowers, spattered with tomato soup, #3
  Monet - Haystacks, smeared with mashed potatoes, #4
  da Vinci - Mona Lisa, covered in cream cake, #2
  Monet - The Artist's Gardens at Giverny, splashed with red paint, #5

 I don't know yet, what the last one is. In any case, the representations of the smears and glue marks is realistic and, together with the colour of the substance in question, serves to identify each painting in the image. (I'm not sure what the lexicographic order refers to. I think it must be the artists' names with common particles such as "van" and "da" ignored, but that puts the Mona Lisa out of order.)

The answer word

 The first number before the slash is an index into the artwork's title. We get a letter for each painting. If we read them off in the hanging order of the paintings, we get: PASTE • S. The sixth letter is still missing, but I think it must be "pastels", which fits nicely with the theme.


Great work! It's strange that I can hardly find the original photo I used in this puzzle (it was almost 6 months ago). However, here's the news report: https://www.artnews.com/art-news/news/botticelli-primavera-climate-protest-1234635182/
